# Opening a HTML document in a browser knowing only its relative path, from a Java function

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to open a HTML document when clicking a jButton. this is the button's code

```
try {
        Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
        URI url = new URI("src/info/index.html");
        dk.browse(url.resolve(url));
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error en btnAyudaActionPerformed:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se puede abrir la ayuda");
    }
```

But it throws

```
Failed to open src/info/src/info/index.html. Error message: The system cannot find the specified file.
```

When I put the absolute path it works correctly, but I cannot put the absolute path because I need to move the jar.

Comment: why would `src` be in your jar file?

Comment: Try using "../../src/info/index.html" as your uri

Comment: src is a directory in the same folder that the .jar. The icons of the project are there and they're shown correctly

Comment: @JaeheonShim. I tried, still not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URI need an absolute path, so I get the file's absolute path:

```
File htmlAyuda = new File("info/index.html");
    String direccion = htmlAyuda.getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
        URI url = new URI(direccion.replace("\\", "/"));
        dk.browse(url.resolve(url));
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error en btnAyudaActionPerformed:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se puede abrir la ayuda");
    }
```

The URI cannot have backslashes, so I have to replace them for normal slashes